# how to redirect type of website based on user-agent

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

[image]

Do you have such kind of experience? If yes, please let me know how many instances do I need to configure like that?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something like the map directive. Example below based on https://serverfault.com/questions/316541/check-several-user-agent-in-nginx

```
http {
  map $http_user_agent $ua_redirect {
    default '';
    ~(iPhone|Android) m.domain1.com;
    ~(MSIE|Mozilla) domain2.com;
  }

  server {
    ...
    location / {
      ...
      if ($ua_redirect != '') {
         return 301 http://$ua_redirect$request_uri;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by single instance? A single location in a config?